# VB.Net File.Copy not copying files and not throwing any exceptions

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have

```
Try
    File.Copy(Source, Destination)
Catch ex As Exception
    ' Roll back
End Try
```

The paths are correct. I have verified it and the source file exists. File.Copy doesn't throw any exceptions. It skips the Catch when debugging. But the file is not copied to the destination folder.

Is there a list of file types that are supported by System.IO? I'm trying to copy a DWF file (plan drawing).

Thanks.

Comment: I don't use ASP.net but check the folder permissions to the folder you want to place the file in

Comment: VB.Net. We have similar copy process on other pages and no complaints there. Thanks. I'm puzzled as to why it's not choking and going in to the Catch code.

Comment: 1) Have you used absolute paths for the source and destination? 2) There is no restriction on the file types supported by System.IO.

Comment: Andrew, the files and paths are constructed from data in an XML file and appended to a base path, which creates an absolute path for a server folder. The source file is also located on the server. It is to be copied to another folder under a different file name. We have the File.Copy on other pages and works fine. Thanks for clarifying #2.

Comment: Sometimes when something mysterious is happening with files, it helps to use [Process Monitor from Windows SysInternals](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb896645) - with an appropriate filter - to see exactly what is going wrong (e.g. a bad filename, insufficient permissions).

Comment: Okay, thanks, Andrew.

Comment: File.Copy wasn't working but System.IO.File.Copy worked, even though I saw System.IO when I hovered over File.Copy. Thanks for everyone's responses.

Comment: I suspect that you are not using [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) - it might have caught something for you which was making your code behave unexpectedly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File.Copy wasn't working but System.IO.File.Copy worked, even though I saw System.IO when I hovered over File.Copy. Thanks for everyone's responses.